# MongoDB Java driver: how to get development version

Tags: java, mongodb, github

Latest stable release of MongoDB Java Driver ([v3.2](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/)) has a bug related to adding a List to an existing Document (cf [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2056)).

The bug seems to be solved in v3.3.0 but this version is not yet released: how can I download (and compile) this latest version (which seems to be on github)?

Many thanks,
Tom

**UPDATE:**

Dev version seems not available on git (see Eclipse screenshot):
[image]

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git` should fetch the latest version. Building and installation instructions can be found here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately when importing with Eclipse eGit, it seems that dev versions are not available (stops at v3.2.3). Will add a screen capture in the post to illustrate.

Comment: Current development version should be in the `master` branch without any version number.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the project and generate the lib (export as jar) and import it...
BUT... consider the fact that if that version has not been rolled out is because is not completely developed, or not completely tested,

so in my opinion you should wait an not fix a bug but taking the risk of porting to your project new bugs or security issues...

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version 3.2.2. Does this help?

According to https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases, 
The 3.2.2 MongoDB Java Driver is a **patch to the 3.2.0 release.**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thx. Not sure to understand: Java driver fix is in v3.3.0. Are you suggesting that this driver is included in MongoDB v3.2.0?